# JQuery Open Child Div via class

Tags: jquery

I need to open the child class / div when click on link:

I have:

```
echo '<td><a class="openhiddenmessage" href="#">'.$title.'</a></td>'; //If user clicks here
echo '<div class="hiddenmessage" style="display:none">'.$message.'</div>';  //This shows up
```

The problem is that theres many so I need to know which belongs to each.

Here is the JQuery:

```
$('.openhiddenmessage').click(function(){
   $('.hiddenmessage').show();
});
```

How can I get it to open ot's child?

UPDATE: For some reason none of the answers given is working so here's the whole part:

```
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><a class="openhiddenmessage" href="#">'.$title.'</a></td>';
echo '<td>'.$date.'</td>';
echo '<td><a id="deletemessage" href="delete.php?id='.$id.'" class="delete">Delete</a></td>';
echo '<div class="hiddenmessage" style="display:none">'.$message.'</div>';  
echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: Please post your rendered HTML and not the PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `div` next to `a` in `td` then you can use `next()` to show the message. This way additional `class` will not needed for `div`. Example:

HTML

```
<td>
    <a class="openhiddenmessage" href="#">Title</a>
    <div style="display:none">Message</div>
</td>
```

OR your PHP code

```
echo '<td>' . 
        '<a class="openhiddenmessage" href="#">' . $title . '</a>' .
        '<div style="display:none">' . $message . '</div>' .
    '<td>';
```

JS

```
$('.openhiddenmessage').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().show();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/p5Pvh/1/)

Answer (score 2):

[**closest**()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) searches up the DOM tree, you will need something like

```
$('.openhiddenmessage').click(function () {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.hiddenmessage').show();
});
```

Edit: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mvWwD/) for your initial HTML

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
$('.openhiddenmessage').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
$(this).closest('div').show();
});
```

I would personally do it with id's though....if you are getting results from a database.

```
 echo '<td><a class="openhiddenmessage" data-id="'.$id.'" href="#">'.$title.'</a></td>'; //If user clicks here
 echo '<div class="hiddenmessage" id="msg-'.$id.'" style="display:none">'.$message.'</div>';
```

Then...

```
  $('.openhiddenmessage').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  $('#msg-'+$(this).data('id')).show();
});
```

That way, you're not restricted to having the message be in the table.
It could be anywhere.  Even a modal style popup would be possible

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are having `div` inside a `tr` which is invalid, you should put your div inside td,

although , you can do this in its current form

```
$('.openhiddenmessage').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('td').next('.hiddenmessage').show();
});
```